# Print if MySQL returns no results

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

This is my code so far. I'm attempting to print `No results found` if no results are returned by MySQL however I can't figure it out. Perhaps I'm using incorrect arguments. Could anyone provide me with an example? Much appreciated!

```
def movie_function(film):
    connection = mysql connection info
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM film_database WHERE film_name = '"+film+"' ORDER BY actor"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row[1]
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see where you are trying to print "No results found". Hint its going to need to be in an `if` statement.

Comment: just check the length of rows. if the len(rows) == 0, print 'No results found'

Comment: you can just check rows itself `if not rows:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute a select statement, `cursor.rowcount` is set to the number of results retrieved. Also, there is no real need to call `cursor.fetchall()`; looping over the cursor directly is easier:

```
def movie_function(film):
    connection = mysql connection info
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM film_database WHERE film_name = %s ORDER BY actor"

    cursor.execute(sql, (film,))
    if not cursor.rowcount:
        print "No results found"
    else:
        for row in cursor:
            print row[1]
```

Note that I also switched your code to use SQL parameters; there is no need to use string interpolation here, leave that to the database adapter. The `%s` placeholder is replaced for you by a correctly quoted value taken from the second argument to `cursor.execute()`, a sequence of values (here a tuple of one element).

Using SQL parameters also lets a good database reuse the query plan for the select statement, and leaving the quoting up to the database adapter prevents SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cursor.rowcount` after your code to see how many rows were actually returned.  See [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this should work.

```
def movie_function(film):
    connection = mysql connection info
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM film_database WHERE film_name = %s ORDER BY actor"

    cursor.execute(sql, [film])
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if not rows:
        print 'No resulrs found'
        return
    for row in rows:
        print row[1]
```

Note, that I changed the way the `film` parameter is passed to query. I don't know, how exactly it should be (this depends on what MySQL driver for python you use), but important thing to know, is that you should not pass your parameters directly to the query string, because of security reasons.

Comment: This won't work; the standard MySQLdb database adapter uses `%s`-style parameters. You need to make the second argument to `.execute()` a sequence, so a tuple or a list. As it stands, if `film` is a string the database adapter will try to treat each individual character as a parameter value, and then complain that there are too many parameters.

Comment: Thanks, as I said, I am not aware of how exactly this adapter implements that.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use :

rows_affected=cursor.execute("SELECT ... ") -> you have directly the number of returned rows

Comment: cursor.execute returns None, or an iterator if the kwarg `multi=True`, not the number of rows affected. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html